Gas cost of simple ETH transfers on Arbitrum
Historically, Arbitrum enforced a minimum of 400k gas for transactions. Here's an example of a simple ETH transfer I performed in July 2023, which cost ~411k gas:
https://arbiscan.io/tx/0x903d44347095c1679763f1497b84e8f643ab9220667c9f9ad4fae60b5067eaa9
I've performed https://arbiscan.io/tx/0xad7fbb850dc18724504a0cf415f6c5a82c25819c689d671db35863a77f88be55 today (May 17, 2024), and I noticed that the cost is 37k gas now:

What gives? Is this due to EIP-4844?
